# connect to Wifi device and Internet at the same time

Tags: android, android-wifi, adhoc

I use smartphone directly connect to AR.Drone (a Wi-Fi quadricopter) use adhoc mode.

The AR.Drone can sent me images captured form the build-in camera.

I want to sync those image to the Internet immediately when AR.Drone sent me the images,

but my Wifi already connect to the AR.Drone.

Is there anyway(maybe use computer) to connect to the AR.Drone and upload images at same time?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to use your phone's tethering/hotspot mode, if it has one.  Then you can use a `wpa_supplicant` program that's been cross-compiled for ARM and run it on the drone to connect to that wifi network.

https://github.com/daraosn/ardrone-wpa2 is a very easy-to-use project that will let your drone connect to an existing wifi network instead of creating its own.  You clone it from github, turn on the drone, connect your laptop to the drone's wifi network and run `script/install`.  Then turn on the phone's hotspot, and from your laptop run `script/connect "<essid>" -p "<password>" -a <address> -d <droneip>` to tell the drone to connect to that network.

Hopefully at that point the phone will have internet connectivity at the same time that it's connected to the drone over wifi.